# How to use `find -exec sh -c` in a git or shell alias

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I am using the following as git shell script.

```sh
    #!/bin/sh

    [ -z "$1" ] && dir="$PWD" || dir="$1"

    find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
        for i; do
            printf "\n%s\n" "$i"
            cd "$i" \
            && git remote update
        done' sh {} +
```

But would like to use a git alias.

```sh
    rmup=!sh -c "find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '\
        for i; do \
            printf "\n%s\n" "$i" && cd "$i" && git remote update; \
        done' sh {} +"
```

or at least a shell alias.

```sh
    alias rmup="find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '\
        for i; do \
            printf "\n%s\n" "$i" && cd "$i" && git remote update; \
        done' sh {} +"
```

I have tried all sort of escaping, single and double-quotes combinations, but without success.

The reason for wanting to use an "embedded" alias is to simplify maintenance and portability between machines as I am already syncing my `.gitconfig` and `.bashrc`.

Forgot to mention that I has also tried a shell function, and while the `printf` prints the directory, the `cd` complains that the directory does not exists.

```
    rmup() {
        find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
            for i; do
               printf "\n%s\n" "$i" && cd "$i" && git remote update;
            done' sh {} +
    }
```

Comment: If you already have a working shell script, why would you need a shell alias?

Comment: Why would you use a shell alias rather than a shell function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use shell aliases unless you absolutely must; shell functions are functionally superior.

```
rmup() {
  local dir=${1:-$PWD}
  find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
    for i; do
      printf "\n%s\n" "$i"
      (cd "$i" && exec git remote update)
    done' _ {} +
}
```

In particular, you can't substitute positional arguments inside an alias, which your code here explicitly needs to do. (Now, you can expand to something which then looks at its positional arguments, but the set of cases in which that technique is usable is... significantly constrained, for reasons I'd rather not go into here).

Usage is exactly the same as what it would be for an alias: `rmup argument`

Comment: I've tried the shell functions, but was getting some weird errors with parsing current directory.  I'll update the question.

Comment: See if you can reproduce those issues with the version as currently posted. :)

Comment: ...to explain why it was problematic, by the way, notice how you were using `.` instead of `$PWD` as the default. Think about what happens when you `cd ./src/foo` and then `cd ./src/bar`; that tries to go to `./src/foo/src/bar`, and if that directory doesn't exist...

Comment: @go2null, ...so the source of your problem there wasn't that it was a function; it was that you wrote it subtly differently than how you wrote your script.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  (It is what I had in the shell script.)  However, I was hardcoding `.` (dot) as current directory in the aliases and that was not working.

Comment: _so the source of your problem there wasn't that it was a function; it was that you wrote it subtly differently than how you wrote your scrip_ Yes, I started with the git alias, then shell alias,  shell function, and finally the git shell script - when I finally stopped using the `.` and implemented `$dir`.

Comment: _Think about what happens when you cd ./src/foo and then_ -> this is why the subshell `(...)` works in your code.

Comment: Quite right; I'm trying to go belt-and-suspenders here -- both using the subshell to scope the change, and using `$PWD` rather than `.` on the `find`. By the way, one could also use the GNU find extension `-execdir`, and have `find` do the `cd`'ing for you.

Comment: `git config alias.shellfunction '!f() { echo $1; echo $2; }; f "$@"'`

Comment: @jthill, when I spoke about limitations on aliases, I was referring to shell aliases, not git aliases.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the shell-script, then name it `git-rmup`, put it in your `$PATH` and you'll be able to call `git rmup` as if it was a Git alias.

Comment: The reason for wanting to use an "embedded" alias is to simplify maintenance and portability between machines as I am already syncing my `.gitconfig` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: Once you understand the exact rules for quoting strings within Git's config file, you wont talk about 'simplify maintainance' anymore I guess ;-). Versionning/syncing a `scripts/` directory next to your other config files would be much simpler IMHO.

Comment: @MatthieuMoys - syncing my entire dotfiles is where I am now, two years later. :-)